# Right Banner Position not visible in Tablets and Phones

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, joomla2.5, tablet

I have added a vertical banner position (div class = "werbe-wrapper") at the RIGHT HAND SIDE of my webpage [golfanatics.de](http://www.golfanatics.de). This position is, however, not shown when looking at the website with a tablet (eg. iPad) or a mobile phone.

The website is based in Joomla, the template allows for a responsive layout which I have DISABLED.

Any idea, where I could look at, in order to have the above position being displayed?

Thanks and cheers,
Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom.css is:

```
/* Handhelds */
@media (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .nomobilebanner {
        display: none !important;
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
/* iPad Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    .nomobilebanner {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .noipadbanner {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This is where your issue is coming from.

Comment: Dear Bakual, unfortunately this did not help: to be on the safe side, I removed all media-CSS-entries, but no change, the sidebar is still not shown on handhelds and iPad-tablet...... Any other ideas? I assume it is somehow related to the width of the wrapper "go_wrap100" .....that one is 1185px and hence wider than the 1024px of iPad. However, I would expect iPad to shrink the page accordingly, as it does on other pages with more than 1024px width (and as it also does in portrait view).....

Comment: Try removing the `overflow:hidden;` from the `.go_wrapall` rule in your custom.css.